# Could you explain how this formula is working on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, swipe

I'm trying to create swipe sencing in JavaScript like this "http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/swipesensejs.html". Can someone explain the distance formula on this?

```
swipeLength = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(curX - startX,2) + Math.pow(curY - startY,2)));
```

I do know sqrt and pow but couldn't figur out how swipe length is calculated.

Comment: Please add in your question what parts of the formula you do or don't understand.

Comment: Difference in x, and difference in y, conceptually make two sides of a right-angled triangle.  The formula uses Pythagoras to calculate the length of the other side of this triangle.  Pythagoras discovered that if you square the two short sides of a right-angled triangle and add them together, that it is equal to the square of the longest side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you calculate the distance between 2 points in a 2d space when the coordinates are known.

[image]

In your code:

- **curX** is **x2** which is the x coordinate of the end point
- **startX** is **x1** which is the x coordinate of the beginning point
- **curY** is **y2** which is the y coordinate of the end point
- **startY** is **y2** which is the y coordinate of the beginning point

Refs:

- [The Distance Formula is a variant of the Pythagorean Theorem](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)
- [Wikipedia entry on distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance)

Comment: Please add the name of the formula in the answer, it's not clear why this formula is cited.

Comment: Added references for your attention

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple distance formula between two points.

[image]

more details on [Distance Formula Explained](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic formula for calculating distance between two points:

[image]

Comment: It's simple pythagorean theorem

Comment: The formula is not really helpful if you don't explain it.

Comment: You want me to cite math sources? I don't think that's what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: No, you don't need to cite any source, you can simply give the name of the formula like @JEY did.

Comment: Yes, you should cite the source (if you copied the image from somewhere) and you should explain the equation—what is *d*? What is *x*? *y*?

Comment: Thank you! I will check pythagorean theorem.